# bash run read a file and run the read line OR command

Tags: bash, operands

two commands with OR condition

`test -e a.txt  || test -e b.txt` this command running without any problem from CLI but if I read from a file and try to run it gives `sh: ||: unknown operand' error`

```
cat test.txt
test -e a.txt  || test -e b.txt
```

Read and Run the command

```
cat test.txt| while read command; do $command;done

sh: ||: unknown operand
```

Any thoughts

Comment: Read this article: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @KenotSolutions: Also, as you see from the error message (_**sh**: ||: unknown operand_), you are not running bash. I suggest that you replace the _bash_ tag by either the _shell_ tag or the _sh_ tag.

Answer (score 1):

Very simplified, bash will:

1. Parse a command or structure, then for each command:
2. Apply brace expansion
3. Apply parameter expansion
4. Do word splitting
5. Apply pathname expansion
6. Execute the result

Handling of `||` happens during parsing in step 1, but you expand it in step 3. As a result, it's treated as a regular string as if running `test -e a.txt "||" test -e b.txt`.

It will similarly fail for commands like `echo {1..10}` which would require re-doing #2, and `echo $PATH` which would require re-doing #3.

Meanwhile, it will work for `echo Hello` (#4) and `ls *.png` (#4/#5) because these only use features that come after.

While having a command in a string is a code smell indicating that you're painting yourself into an awkward corner, you can use `eval` to apply all the steps over from #1 on a string of your choice:

```
cmd="test -e a.txt || test -e b.txt"
eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: Since the code is reading multiple commands and executing them (/trying to), using `. test.txt` or `source test.txt` might be a better option.

Comment: As written, most definitely. If it's in a loop due to to logging/retries/parallelization, then it depends.